# Role is invalid or cannot be assumed on sls deploy

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I've got error on sls deploy:

`Role arn:aws:iam::542779088875:role/serverless-role is invalid or cannot be assumed`

I don't understand where this role comes from. At first, I didn't have role named like this. Then, I've created new role named `serverless-role` and selected it at dashboard.serverless.com, but I still get this error.

Stack removal doesn't help either (I get the same error).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverless tries to create Stack with this **CloudFormation** role, so creating CloudFormation role named `serverless-role` worked out.